# chrome 62, highchart v4.2.5 , Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in arguments_marker

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts

My  web application which is using highchart v4.2.5  runs fine. However,when I update chrome to  62.0.3202.62, It goes wrong. Here is the error message:

```
highcharts.unminified.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in arguments_marker
at forEach (<anonymous>)
at s (highcharts.unminified.js:25)
at c.drawTrackerGraph [as drawTracker] (highcharts.unminified.js:330)
at c.render (highcharts.unminified.js:271)
at highcharts.unminified.js:232
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at s (highcharts.unminified.js:25)
at C.Chart.renderSeries (highcharts.unminified.js:231)
at C.Chart.render (highcharts.unminified.js:233)
at C.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.unminified.js:236)
```

Only the data and the chrome version will results in the problem.Data is too big, so I keep it in a txt file.However , I can't upload the txt file, so I just give a sample of the data. My javascript code is as follows:

```
<div id="perfCPU"></div>

var mydata = [{x: "1509562856000",y: 137.55},{x: "1509562857000",y: 137.67},{x: "1509562858000",y: 137.67},{x: "1509562859000",y: 137.68},{x: "1509562861000",y: 137.83},{x: "1509562862000",y: 137.89}]
specialLine({domId: 'perfCPU', unit: "%", name: 'CPU', data: mydata,color: '#ffc966'})  
function formatTime(unixTimeStamp) {
   var date = new Date(unixTimeStamp) ;
    var hours = date.getHours()
    var minutes = "0" +  date.getMinutes()  //如果是3分4秒,那么返回的分钟数字是3.如果是13分4秒,返回的分钟数字是13
    var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds()
    return hours + ":" + minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds.substr(-2) //-2是从倒数第2个元素开始

}
function specialLine(config) {
//计算tickPositions的值
//转化data的横坐标为数字
    var length = config.data.length
    if (length > 0) {
    var i =0 ;

    for (i; i< length; i++) {
        config.data[i].x =  config.data[i].x - '' //将 "1487312495" to number
    }

    var startTime = config.data[0].x - '';
    var endTime = config.data[length - 1].x - '';
    var interval = ~~((endTime - startTime) /3)

    var tickPositions = [];
    if (length >=4) {
        tickPositions = [startTime,startTime +interval,startTime +2*interval,endTime]
    }else if(length == 3) {
        tickPositions = [startTime, ~~((endTime + startTime)/2),endTime]
    } else if(length == 2) {
        tickPositions = [startTime,endTime]
    } else if(length == 1) {
        tickPositions = [startTime]
    }

    Highcharts.chart(config.domId, {
        title: {
            text: '',
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickPositions: tickPositions,
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    //将timestamp转化为日期
                    return formatTime(this.value)
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            //将timestamp转化为时间
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                //return DrawPic.formatTime(this.point.x) + '<br>' + config.name + ':' +this.point.y + config.unit
                var showHtml = formatTime(this.point.x) + '<br>' + config.name + ':' +this.point.y + config.unit
                return showHtml
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            series: {
                color: '#ffc966',
                turboThreshold:0
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'whatever',
            data: config.data
        }]
    });
} 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phbLL3q8/

Comment: I'm getting this too. Works ok in Safari.

Comment: you should file an issue with the highcharts library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an internal issue with highcharts.

Comment: I  will delete the javascript tag ,ok ? don't close my question.

Comment: @WillStone  However , I must fix the bug in the  google chrome. The bug only exists in chrome 62.0.3202.62. In chrome  61.0.3163.100 , it works fine.

Comment: I found that it’s a known issue with Chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=777836